# How to create a dataframe from a string key=value delimited by ";"

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive table with the structure:

[image]

I need to read the string field, breaking the keys and turn into a Hive table columns, the final table should look like this:

[image]

**Very important, the number of keys in the string is dynamic and the name of the keys is also dynamic**

An attempt would be to read the string with Spark SQL, create a dataframe with the schema based on all the strings and use saveAsTable () function to transform the dataframe the hive final table, but do not know how to do this

Any suggestion ?

Comment: How far have you gotten with splitting the keys and values on semicolons?

Comment: currently do with a hive query however is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive (assuming unique `(code, date)` combinations and no embedded `=` and `;` in the `string`) can look like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, split}

val df = Seq(
    (1, 1, "key1=value11;key2=value12;key3=value13;key4=value14"),
    (1, 2, "key1=value21;key2=value22;key3=value23;key4=value24"),
    (2, 4, "key3=value33;key4=value34;key5=value35")
).toDF("code", "date", "string")

val bits = split($"string", ";")
val kv = split($"pair", "=")

df
  .withColumn("bits", bits)  // Split column by `;`
  .withColumn("pair", explode($"bits"))  // Explode into multiple rows
  .withColumn("key", kv(0))  // Extract key
  .withColumn("val", kv(1))  // Extract value 
  // Pivot to wide format
  .groupBy("code", "date")
  .pivot("key")
  .agg(first("val"))

// +----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |code|date|   key1|   key2|   key3|   key4|   key5|
// +----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |   1|   2|value21|value22|value23|value24|   null|
// |   1|   1|value11|value12|value13|value14|   null|
// |   2|   4|   null|   null|value33|value34|value35|
// +----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

This can be easily adjust to handle the case when `(code, date)` are not unique and you can process more complex `string` patterns using `UDF`.

Depending on a language you use and a number of columns you may be better with using `RDD` or `Dataset`. It is also worth to consider dropping full `explode` / `pivot` in favor of an UDF.

```scala
val parse = udf((text: String) => text.split(";").map(_.split("=")).collect {
  case Array(k, v) => (k, v)
}.toMap)

val keys = udf((pairs: Map[String, String]) => pairs.keys.toList)

// Parse strings to Map[String, String]
val withKVs = df.withColumn("kvs", parse($"string"))

val keys = withKVs
  .select(explode(keys($"kvs"))).distinct // Get unique keys
  .as[String] 
  .collect.sorted.toList // Collect and sort

// Build a list of expressions for subsequent select
val exprs = keys.map(key => $"kvs".getItem(key).alias(key)) 

withKVs.select($"code" :: $"date" :: exprs: _*)
```

In Spark 1.5 you can try:

```scala
val keys = withKVs.select($"kvs").rdd
  .flatMap(_.getAs[Map[String, String]]("kvs").keys)
  .distinct
  .collect.sorted.toList
```

Comment: unfortunately I am using spark 1.5 and the pivot function is not available, would otherwise do not use it?

Comment: The second method after replacing `Dataset` with RDD should work just fine.

Comment: the .select does not work with RDD, where I have to change?

Comment: `withKVs.select($"kvs").rdd.flatMap(_.getAs[Map[String, String]]("kvs").keys).distinct` - collect, and the rest as before.

Comment: sorry, I never worked with scala 

I stopped on the line:
`// Parse strings to Map [String, String]
val = withKVs df.withColumn ("kvs" parse ($ "string"))`

what comes next ?